# How does a Wi-Fi suggestion actually work for Android 11?

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-11

I been reading the following documentation (linked below) regarding the Wi-Fi Suggestions API which is recommended to be used for network configurations. For earlier Android versions, we had other alternatives and I found those quite straight forward but finding trouble fully understanding some things with this API.

For example, there is a note that says `Wi-Fi suggestions are not saved networks and will not appear in the saved network page.`

What are suggestions? Is it just a dialog prompt on the screen or does it actually save some configuration profile to the device?

Also I noted there is a new title in the Wi-Fi picker on Android 11 titled `Subscriptions` and displayed my passpoint configuration I created (even though I cannot get to display again). Is this related to the Suggestions API?

Can somebody please just elaborate this a little further or just let me know if they had any experience using this API so far?

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-suggest